# How to use optional positional arguments with nargs='*' arguments in argparse?

Tags: python, parsing, argparse, optparse, optional-arguments

As shown in the following code, I want to have an optional positional argument `files`, I want to specify a default value for it, when paths are passed in, use specified path.

But because `--bar` can have multiple arguments, the path passed in didn't go into `args.files`, how do I fix that? Thanks!

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo')
parser.add_argument('--bar', nargs='*')
parser.add_argument('files', nargs='?')

cmd = '--foo a --bar b c d '
print parser.parse_args(cmd.split())
# Namespace(bar=['b', 'c', 'd'], files=None, foo='a')


cmd = '--foo a --bar b c d /path/to/file1'
print parser.parse_args(cmd.split())
# Namespace(bar=['b', 'c', 'd', '/path/to/file1'], files=None, foo='a')
```

Comment: How is `argparse` supposed to know that `/path/to/file1` goes with `files` and not with `bar`?

Answer (score 1):

Your argument spec is inherently ambiguous (since `--bar` can take infinite arguments, there is no good way to tell when it ends, particularly since `files` is optional), so it requires user disambiguation. Specifically, `argparse` can be told "this is the end of the switches section, all subsequent argument are positional" by putting `--` before the positional only section. If you do:

```
cmd = '--foo a --bar b c d -- /path/to/file1'
print parser.parse_args(cmd.split())
```

You should get:

```
Namespace(bar=['b', 'c', 'd'], files='/path/to/file1', foo='a')
```

(Tested on Py3, but should apply to Py2 as well)

Alternatively, the user can pass the positional argument anywhere it's unambiguous by avoiding putting positional arguments after `--bar` e.g.:

```
cmd = '/path/to/file1 --foo a --bar b c d'
```

or

```
cmd = '--foo a /path/to/file1 --bar b c d'
```

Lastly, you could avoid using `nargs='*'` for switches, given the ambiguity it introduces. Instead, define `--bar` to be accepted multiple times with a single value per switch, accumulating all uses to a `list`:

```
parser.add_argument('--bar', action='append')
```

then you pass `--bar` multiple times to supply multiple values one at a time, instead of passing it once with many values:

```
cmd = '--foo a --bar b --bar c --bar d /path/to/file1'
```